# Developing Rtf Reader on Android

Tags: android, rtf

I need to develop primitive reader on Android, which would read formats txt, rtf
Has how much understood, problems will be with a Rtf format. That it is possible to use to open document Rtf? And if there are somewhere examples of work with Rtf?